# Toggle submenu and if child clicked go to page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've built a simple toggle menu that when clicked once shows a list of child elements and if clicked again hides those visible elements.

If a child element is clicked however I want it to visit that page only I cant seem to get it working? Is it to do with my prevent Default?

```
//  Language select in global nav
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e) {

if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active')) {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
    $(this).css('height', 'auto');
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
} else {
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65);
    $(this).children('ul').show();
}

e.preventDefault();
});
```

Here is the [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzzvLa4j/)

Comment: I think your code is working fine. What exactly is the issue?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney He has provided the fiddle.

Comment: If you click English, then try click international you should be taken to Google.com @void...

Comment: but google.com has set some request headers which doesn't allow you to open google.com in just any iframe.

Comment: missed that @void - thanks

Comment: yes , your issue is with preventDefault. try to remove e.preventdefault from your code and add href="#" to your link to English. it will work. i have tried this in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simple transform your main menu element in paragraph tag ?
or you could put an # inside your main menu element, and delete prevent default. 
In this way you don't need to prevent default on your main elements.

Although google.com doesn't load inside an iFrame, you could check this fiddle. It works.

Look at this (with # in the anchors) [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzzvLa4j/4/)

HTML

```
<ul style=" ">
  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="#">English</a>
    <ul style="">
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">International</a></li>
      <li><a href="">UK &amp; Ireland</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="#">Espanol</a>
    <ul style="">
      <li><a href="/es-es/">Español</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">España</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="#">Francais</a>
    <ul style="">
      <li><a href="/fr-fr/">Français</a></li>
      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">France</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks @Gianca, I cant change the empty anchors to p tags though im afraid so have to work with the markup provided...

Comment: uhm ok, so put a # inside the A tag... or prevent default only for those elements and not for the others. You could add class to those element and prevent default only for that class. I'll modify my fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Here Check [This](https://jsfiddle.net/hzzvLa4j/7/) Out.

**Explaination**.

Instead of delegating the event on the whole `li`, I bound the event to all the immediate `<a>` children of the li, and then prevent the propagation for that specific element. So we don't have to figure out how to stop the event propagation (`click` in our case) to the children element.

Also the JSFiddle may have loading external `iframe` problems, so check the solution out [here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/hzzvLa4j/7/show/light/).

Answer (score 0):

Add this line before your code

```
$('.sub-lang > a').removeAttr('href');
```

Remove

```
e.preventDefault();
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 0):

You should add one condition for that.

```
if($(e.target).parent().hasClass('sub-lang') )
```

It will allow you to click on submenu.

```js
//  Language select in global nav
$('.sub-lang').on('click', function(e) {
  
 if($(e.target).parent().hasClass('sub-lang') ){
 
    if ($(this).hasClass('active') && $(e.target).parent().hasClass('active')) {
      $(this).removeClass('active');
      $(this).css('height', 'auto');
      $(this).children('ul').hide();
    } else {
      $(this).addClass('active');
      $(this).css('height', $(this).find('ul').height() + 65);
      $(this).children('ul').show();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```css
ul li ul {
    display: none;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 250px;
}
ul li.active ul {
    display: block;
    text-align:left;
    background: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul style=" ">
  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="">English</a>
    <ul style="">

      <li><a href="http://www.google.com" traget="_blank">International</a></li>

      <li><a href="">UK &amp; Ireland</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

 
  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="/es-es/">Español</a>
    <ul style="">

      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">España</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

  <li class="sub-lang">
    <a href="/fr-fr/">Français</a>
    <ul style="">

      <li><a href="http://www.google.com">France</a></li>

    </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hzzvLa4j/10/)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add stopPropagation in your inside list items.

```js
$('.sub-lang ul li').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```